# Hand-assembling an x86 call instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Out of curiosity, I decided to hand-assemble some x86 code. I'm doing all right so far, but I just cannot figure out the proper encoding for the `call` instruction.

I get that it's basically supposed to be `E8 xx xx xx xx`, where `xx xx xx xx` is the address I want to jump to.

The way that I tried encoding this is like so (NASM):

```
extern _printf

; ...

db 0xe8
dd _printf
```

That assembles and links just fine, but the program crashes.

I looked at how NASM assembles the instruction `call _printf`, and it generates a different `xx xx xx xx` than mine does. I wondered if I was specifying the address incorrectly or something, but the code

```
times 512 nop
dd _printf
times 512 nop
```

yields a gazillion `90`s surrounding the same address I got from my hand-assembled `call`, which means the actual address of `_printf` isn't what I'm supposed to be passing.

What am I missing here?

(Also: I was curious about the other encoding for `call`, the one that starts with `FF`. What's the difference?)

Comment: `E8` uses relative addressing: _"`E8 cd` `CALL rel32` Call near, relative, displacement relative to next instruction. 32-bit displacement sign extended to 64-bits in 64-bit mode."_ Refer to Intel's Software Developer's Manual Vol 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0xE8 is used with relative address. So the following instruction is encoded as E8 00 00 00 00

```
  call label
label:
```

Some encodings starting with 0xFF can be used for indirect calls where address of the destination is stored in register or memory. If you want to call procedure at specific address, you can do the following:

```
  mov  eax, 0x12345678 ; address of procedure (not relative)
  call eax
```

0x9A encoding allows you to make far calls that update CS-register as well. So for example:

```
  call 0x1234:0x55667788
```

updates value of the CS-register to 0x1234 and the value of the instruction pointer to 0x55667788. Return address is also pushed to stack with values for both CS and instruction pointer.

For more information about different encodings I recommend [this reference](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2005/readings/i386/CALL.htm).